# Android service calling onDestroy before workerthread ends

Tags: android, service, ondestroy

I have a service that I'm using to send SOAP Webservice calls. Everything is working perfectly and it never crashes, but I kinda think it should.

My problem is that when I have long running queries (10-50 sec.) onDestroy() is called before my workerthread is done (and I call stopSelfResult). Could it be that System.out.println isn't executed right away/out of sync (cached) in the LogCat window?

The is how a start the service through QueryBase class:

```
QueryBase someService  = new QueryBase(myActivity);
someService.execute(...);
```

My QueryBase Class

```
public class QueryBase {

private WeakReference<Activity> currentActivity = null;

private static class ResponseHandler extends Handler {
    private QueryBase mQueryBase;

    public ResponseHandler(QueryBase vQueryBase) {
        mQueryBase = vQueryBase;
    };

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        Bundle extras = message.getData();

        mQueryBase.handleResult(message.arg1,message.arg2,extras.getInt("FRAMEID"),extras.getString("RESPONSE"));
        mQueryBase=null;
    };
};

public QueryBase(Activity vActivity) {
    currentActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(vActivity);
}

/***************************************************************************
 * Start the service
 **************************************************************************/
public boolean execute(Activity vActivity, int cmdID, int frameID, String serverAddress, int requestType, String request) {

    // Valid activity
    if (vActivity==null) return false;

    // Test to see if network is connected
    if (!isOnline(vActivity)) return false;

    Intent webService                           = new Intent(vActivity, WebService.class);
    final ResponseHandler responseHD        = new ResponseHandler(this);
    Messenger messenger                     = new Messenger(responseHD);

    webService.putExtra("QUERYRESULT_MESSENGER",messenger);
    webService.putExtra("CMDID", cmdID);
    webService.putExtra("FRAMEID",frameID);
    webService.putExtra("SERVER_ADDRESS",serverAddress);
    webService.putExtra("REQUEST_TYPE",requestType);
    webService.putExtra("REQUEST",request);

    vActivity.startService(webService);     

    return true;
}

/***************************************************************************
 * Is my Android connected?
 **************************************************************************/
private Boolean isOnline(Activity vActivity) {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) vActivity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) return true;
    else return false;
}

/***************************************************************************
 * Get current Activity
 **************************************************************************/
public Activity getCurrentActivity() {
    Activity ac = currentActivity.get();
    if (ac!=null) {
        if ((ac.isFinishing()) || (ac.activityDestroyed)) {
            return null;
        };
    }
    return ac;
};

/***************************************************************************
 * XML result from webservice
 **************************************************************************/
public void handleResult(int resultCode, int cmdID, int frameID, String response) {
    System.out.println("DEFAULT HANDLER: ResultCode: " + resultCode);
};

}
```

My WebService Class

```
public class WebService extends Service {

public static final int WS_RT_BLOOSOAP  = 0;
public static final int WS_RT_RSS       = 1;

public static final int WS_RESULT_OK = 0;
public static final int WS_RESULT_UNABLE_TO_CONNECT = 2;
public static final int WS_RESULT_INVALID_REQUEST = 3;
public static final int WS_RESULT_UNKNOWN_ERROR = 999;

static private SparseBooleanArray workList=null;        // Only one job with the same frameID is allowed to run

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    System.out.println("#### WebService onCreate");
    if (workList==null) workList = new SparseBooleanArray();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    System.out.println("#### WebService onDestroy");
}

/***************************************************************************
 * Start working
 **************************************************************************/
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    System.out.println("WebService Start ID=" + startId);

    final int currentID         = startId;
    final Intent currentIntent = intent;

    Runnable workerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("WebService Thread Start - ID=" + currentID);

            int resultCode;

            Bundle responseExtras = new Bundle();

            resultCode = serverRequest(currentIntent,responseExtras);
            sendResponse(currentIntent,resultCode,responseExtras);

            System.out.println("WebService Thread End - ID=" + currentID);

            Bundle  extras = currentIntent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                int frameID = extras.getInt("FRAMEID");             
                System.out.println(">>>>>>> PUT FALSE " + frameID);                 
                workList.put(frameID, false);
            };

            stopSelfResult(currentID);
        }
    };

    if (intent!=null) {
        Bundle  extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            int frameID = extras.getInt("FRAMEID");

            Boolean found = workList.get(frameID,false);
            if (!found) {
                System.out.println(">>>>>>> PUT TRUE FRAMEID=" + frameID);                  
                workList.put(frameID, true);

                Thread workerThread = new Thread(workerRunnable);
                workerThread.start();
            } else {
                System.out.println(">>>>>>> Allready running FRAMEID=" + frameID);                  
            }
        };
    };

    return Service.START_STICKY;
};

/***************************************************************************
 * No binding
 **************************************************************************/
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

/***************************************************************************
 * Send webservice request and return result in responseExtras
 **************************************************************************/
private int serverRequest(Intent intent, Bundle responseExtras) {
  ...
};

/***************************************************************************
 * Send response back to service caller using Messenger.send()
 **************************************************************************/
private boolean sendResponse(Intent intent, int resultCode, Bundle responseExtras) {
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service is stopped if you call `stopSelfResult()` with the latest `startId`. So if the service gets started with an intent for startId=1 and another intent with startId=2 and the second is finished before the first, you call `stopSelfResult(2)` before you finished for startId=1. The service gets destroyed immediately if you call `stopSelfResult()` with the latest startId and no other intents are pending.

Hold the latest startId. Add all startIds you wish to process in an array (e.g. `List<Integer> runningStartIds`) and remove them when you've finished processing them. After removing on finishing, compare the current startId with the latest one and do **not** call `stopSelfResult()` if runningStartIds is not empty. So you will end up calling `stopSelfResult()` only for the latest startId, when all intents were processed and no more intents are pending.

Should work, although I haven't posted an example.

.:EDIT:.
Explenation:
The next `Intent` may come in as fast as you return from `onStartCommand()` regardless of what you're doing in the background.

.:EDIT:.
Not an Improvement(Improvement:
Thinking about that, in fact you only have to keep the `mLastStartId`. Just skip calling `stopSelfResult()` until the finished startId matches `mLastStartId`.)

Comment: Awesome. I didn't think about that, but it makes perfectly sense. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your improvement. I'm not sure that changes anything. As I see it, the problem would be the same if finished startId=2 and mLastStartID=2 and startId=1 is running longer then startId=2? How about using a reference counter (AtomicInteger) and then call stopSelfResult with the highest startId when the reference counter hit 0?

Comment: You're right. My improvement was wrong. A reference counter should also do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it always can be happen. Actually, android application components' life cycle aren't synchronized w/ any type of worker threads as default.

So, you may need to check the status of Service manually, for example you can have one boolean flag to indicate if a service is working or not. Another handy approach is using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) instead of using normal service, it handles worker thread and life-cycle features by itself.

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {
    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService ");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // This callback-method is called inside worker thread, 
        // so you can do some long-time network job here.
        SystemClock.sleep(30000); // 30 seconds
        // In this timing the service will be stopped automatically.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use IntentService because each request/intent is executed in turn using only one worker thread (work queue). The basic idea is to start e.g. 3 soap request and when the result comes back, I can present is in one of 3 views. If I use IntentService request 2 and 3 will wait for a long time if the first request connects to a slow server.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with the flag to indicate if a service is working or not. Are you saying that I can not avoid the call to onDestroy() before the worker thread ends? I don't understand why Android calls it when a) my activity is in front and running and b) my worker thread is running. Isn't the basic idea that a service is running in the background and usually should have a longer life cycle the my activity (except when Android runs out of resources). If not, how can you make a music player that keeps playing in the background?